# Comparing two tables in R to find what products customer is not purchasing

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tables as follows:

```
Cust_list <- data.frame(
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
Customer = c("Mike S.","Tim P."),
Type = c("Shoes","Socks"),
Product_ID = c(233,6546)
)


Product_Table <- data.frame(
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
Product_ID = c(233,256,296,8536,6546,8946),
Type = c("Shoes","Shoes","Shoes", "Socks","Socks","Socks")
)
```

I'm looking to identify the "Product_ID" that the "Customer" is NOT purchasing within the "Type".

For example, Mike S. purchased Product ID = "233" and Type = "Shoes" but not Product IDs = "256" and "296" under "Shoes".  Since Mike S. did not purchase Type = "Socks", this will not be included in the output.

Output table is below.

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select(Cust_list, -Product_ID) %>%
  left_join(Product_Table, 'Type')%>%
  anti_join(Cust_list)

 Customer  Type Product_ID
1  Mike S. Shoes        256
2  Mike S. Shoes        296
3   Tim P. Socks       8536
4   Tim P. Socks       8946
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Cust_list %>% full_join(Product_Table) %>% arrange(Type) %>% 
           fill(Customer,.direction = 'down') %>% anti_join(Cust_list)
Joining, by = c("Type", "Product_ID")
Joining, by = c("Customer", "Type", "Product_ID")
  Customer  Type Product_ID
1  Mike S. Shoes        256
2  Mike S. Shoes        296
3   Tim P. Socks       8536
4   Tim P. Socks       8946
```