# Comparing two tables in R to find what products customer is not purchasing with a set of conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have two tables as follows:

```
Cust_list <- data.frame(
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
Customer = c("Mike S.","Tim P.","Steve Z."),
Type = c("Shoes","Socks", "Shoes"),
Product_ID = c(233,6546,296)
)


Product_Table <- data.frame(
stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
Product_ID = c(233,256,296,8536,6546,8946),
Type = c("Shoes","Shoes","Shoes", "Socks","Socks","Socks"),
SubType = c("Basketball", "Basketball", "Baseball", "Ankle", "Knee-High", "Mid")
)
```

I'm looking to identify the "Product_ID" that the "Customer" is NOT purchasing within the "Type".

For example, Steve Z. purchased Product ID = "296" and Type = "Shoes" but not Product IDs = "233" and "256" under "Shoes". Since Steve Z. did not purchase Type = "Socks", this will not be included in the output.

One additional caveat, if a Customer purchases a Product ID related to the SubType = "Basketball" do not output the Product ID's related to "Basketball".  Since Mike S. already purchased Basketball Shoes, the other Product ID related to Basketball shoes is NOT included in the output.

Output table is below.

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two tables in R to find what products customer is not purchasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808479/comparing-two-tables-in-r-to-find-what-products-customer-is-not-purchasing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer provided by Onyambu for the original post, you can do as follows.

```
library(dplyr)

out <- Cust_list %>%
  left_join(Product_Table) %>%
  select(Customer, SubType) %>%
  filter(SubType == 'Basketball')

select(Cust_list, -Product_ID) %>%
  left_join(Product_Table) %>%
  anti_join(Cust_list) %>%
  anti_join(out)

#   Customer  Type Product_ID    SubType
# 1  Mike S. Shoes        296   Baseball
# 2   Tim P. Socks       8536      Ankle
# 3   Tim P. Socks       8946        Mid
# 4 Steve Z. Shoes        233 Basketball
# 5 Steve Z. Shoes        256 Basketball
```

Comment: Thanks rjen, I guess my question was what if I only wanted the condition to apply where Subtype = "Basketball" and not all of the SubTypes being purchased by Customers in the "out" variable created above?